# Multiple product selection drop-downs

Tags: commerce

I want to set up products with the following attributes: Size, Shape, Power and Colour. Each product will have one of the following attributes. The shape attribute determines the picture. Each shape will exist in multiple sizes, power ratings and colours. For many products having a single dropdown - which is the normal way to use Commerce - will present a confusing number of options 20 sizes, 5 power options and 10 colours - would give 1000 options.

Is it possible to set Commerce up with the 1000 products referred to above which a presented to the purchaser via 4 dropdowns ? The first selects the shape ( this pulls the picture ) and then below there are three other dropdowns for each of the other attributes. Selecting the other options needs to be able to pull different prices.

Any thoughts on how to approach getting Commerce to do this would be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the product page with a 'multi-select' product(sku) field by setting the number of values to unlimited. Select those sku that relate to the product page when editing the content page.

By default you will get a display with a select list.

Making the interaction 'dependent'. Rather than just selecting blue-size-4 being able to select 'size' then 'colour' then custom javascript will be required.

Note that the product fields are customisable so you can always add a 'size' field to product type. If size results in different prices you are back to the n*size product items. If you can find a way to communicate the logic to the customer the price could be adjusted using a rule on checkout.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - sorry about delay in replying - I thought this forum auto-emailed responses !   Yes, this is probably a Javascript challenge as you say.  But I'm playing with your idea.  Thanks again.